# How to convert query syntax to method syntax

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm fooling around trying to learn the ins an outs of LINQ.  I want to convert the following query (which is working correctly) from query syntax to method syntax, but I can't seem to get it right.  Can anyone show me the correct way to accomplish that?

```
var logQuery = from entry in xDoc.Descendants("logentry")
               where (entry.Element("author").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText) ||
                      entry.Element("msg").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText) ||
                      entry.Element("paths").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText) ||
                      entry.Element("revision").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText))
               select new
               {
                   Revision = entry.Attribute("revision").Value,
                   Author = entry.Element("author").Value,
                   CR = LogFormatter.FormatCR(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                   Date = LogFormatter.FormatDate(entry.Element("date").Value),
                   Message = LogFormatter.FormatComment(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                   ET = LogFormatter.FormatET(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                   MergeFrom = LogFormatter.FormatMergeFrom(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                   MergeTo = LogFormatter.FormatMergeTo(entry.Element("msg").Value)
               };
```

Comment: For info, the later chapters in "C# in Depth" cover this area in glorious detail.

Comment: The C# 3.0 specification is available on the internet; it describes the syntactic transformation rules in great detail.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is actually pretty simple;

```
from entry in A
where B
```

translates (literally) to:

```
A.Where(entry=>B)
```

and:

```
select C
```

translates directly to (with "entry" as our context):

```
.Select(entry=>C)
```

(except for when it would be `entry=>entry`, which the compiler omits for non-trivial cases)

so just inject those and you're done:

```
var logQuery = xDoc.Descendants("logentry")
               .Where(entry=>
                          entry.Element("author").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText) ||
                          entry.Element("msg").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText) ||
                          entry.Element("paths").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText) ||
                          entry.Element("revision").Value.ToLower().Contains(matchText))
                .Select(entry=>new
                   {
                       Revision = entry.Attribute("revision").Value,
                       Author = entry.Element("author").Value,
                       CR = LogFormatter.FormatCR(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                       Date = LogFormatter.FormatDate(entry.Element("date").Value),
                       Message = LogFormatter.FormatComment(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                       ET = LogFormatter.FormatET(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                       MergeFrom = LogFormatter.FormatMergeFrom(entry.Element("msg").Value),
                       MergeTo = LogFormatter.FormatMergeTo(entry.Element("msg").Value)
                   });
```

Comment: +1 for a nice, clean answer explaining the principle rather than just a solution to the specific example.

Comment: Bart De Smet wrote a convenient translation [cheat sheet](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/08/30/c-3-0-query-expression-translation-cheat-sheet.aspx) to go between method and query syntax.